# How do I ask Paperclip if I'm uploading a new file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to do some processing on an image the first time it's uploaded. The model can be updated without updating the image and I want to avoid extra processing in those situations. How can I write a check to only process the image if the image is *new*, like being replaced?

Something like:

```
def update
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  @model.process_image if @model.image_is_different_from_existing?
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a solution that looks for relevant params in the `update` or `create` method.

Something like this:

**user.rb**

```
def attachments
  %w(banner footer logo)
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new_resources?
  attaching = []
  @user.attachments.each do |a|
    attaching << a if params[:user][a].present?
  end
  return true unless attaching.empty?
end

def attaching
  []
end

def update
  ...
  if @user.request_necessary? && new_resources?
    action_response << "Server updated: new #{attaching} uploaded."
    redirect_to users_path, notice: action_response.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one way if the photos you are uploading have unique name, Let's say paperclip attribute name is `image`, paperclip creates a column named `image_file_name`, before saving you can check whether the image file name present in your database matches with the name of image file you are uploading or not. I've implemented something like this, below is the snippet

```
product_images = product.product_attachments.pluck(:photo_file_name)

unless product_images.include?("name_of_the_image_i_am_uploading")
  product.product_attachments.create!(:photo => File.open("/home/rajdeepb/Photo/#{data_array[1]}")) if all_images.include?("/home/rajdeepb/Photo/#{name_of_the_image_i_am_uploading}")
end
```

THis might not be the perfect solution but it may be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Part of the processing includes renaming files which seems problematic, unless I can check the pre-post name against what's stored in the database? It feels like there should be a better way though. Esp. if somehow the names match that'd fail.